# DataFrame Pandas - Flatten dataframe using index and column name as the new column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my problem.

I have a data frame like this

```
   A B C
d1 1 2 3
d2 4 5 6
```

I want to generate the dataframe like this.

```
   A-d1 B-d1 C-d1 A-d2 B-d2 C-d2
    1    2    3    4    5    6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for Series with `MultiIndex`, then flatten it in list comprehension and pass to DataFrame constructor:

```
s = df.stack()
#python 3.6+
df1 = pd.DataFrame([s.values],  columns=[f'{j}-{i}' for i, j in s.index])
#python bellow 3.6
#df1 = pd.DataFrame([s.values],  columns=['{}-{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in s.index])
print (df1)
   A-d1  B-d1  C-d1  A-d2  B-d2  C-d2
0     1     2     3     4     5     6
```

Or flatten data by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and create new columns by [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from  itertools import product

c = [f'{j}-{i}' for i, j in product(df.index, df.columns)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame([df.values.ravel()], columns=c)
print (df1)
   A-d1  B-d1  C-d1  A-d2  B-d2  C-d2
0     1     2     3     4     5     6
```