# Transforming Python Dataframe to combine column and row headers into new table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to combine a column and a row to make a new column where a value will be stored? I have a dataframe below that I would like to format to achieve the output at the bottom. Any help would be appreciated. The following table is extracted using beautifulsoup, pandas and selenium. I'll use the sixth df as an example.

Current code

```
s = Service(r'C:\Users\user34\Documents\Python\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

url = "http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSDReportServlet"

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    
df = pd.read_html(str(soup))

df[6] #output below

   GENERATION   GENERATION.1    GENERATION.2    GENERATION.3
0   GROUP         MC               TNG               DCR
1   GAS          10884              7638             59
2   HYDRO         894               103              229
3   ENERGY STORAGE  70               0                56
4   SOLAR          1088              558              0
5   WIND           2780              170              0
6   OTHER           444              279              0
7   DUAL FUEL        0                0               0
8   COAL            1286             819              0
9   TOTAL           17446            9567            344
```

I would like to drop the column headers and the group value. The desired output is:

```
GAS MC   GAS TNG   GAS DCR   HYDRO MC    HYDRO TNG    HYDRO DCR 

10884     7638       59        894         103           229
```

Then extended for the rest of the data, I couldn't fit the whole desired output. Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185860/dataframe-pandas-flatten-dataframe-using-index-and-column-name-as-the-new-colu

Comment: How is this related to selenium and BeautifulSoup? Are you trying to extract some information from some website, and put it in some tabular format? If so, what's the url, and what information are you looking for? This sounds too much like an XY Problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm pulling data from http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSDReportServlet and trying to format tables such as df[6] when using bs4 and pd.read_html. Sorry about the inconvience, this is my first question on this website and I started learning python two weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this (without the overheads of selenium) would be what you're after?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSDReportServlet'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select('table[border="1"]')[1]
df = pd.read_html(str(table), skiprows=1, index_col=['GROUP'])[0]
s = df.stack()
result_df = pd.DataFrame([s.values],  columns=[f'{i} {j}' for i, j in s.index])
print(result_df)
```

Result in terminal:

|  | GAS MC | GAS TNG | GAS DCR | HYDRO MC | HYDRO TNG | HYDRO DCR | ENERGY STORAGE MC | ENERGY STORAGE TNG | ENERGY STORAGE DCR | SOLAR MC | SOLAR TNG | SOLAR DCR | WIND MC | WIND TNG | WIND DCR | OTHER MC | OTHER TNG | OTHER DCR | DUAL FUEL MC | DUAL FUEL TNG | DUAL FUEL DCR | COAL MC | COAL TNG | COAL DCR | TOTAL MC | TOTAL TNG | TOTAL DCR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10884 | 7677 | 59 | 894 | 174 | 229 | 70 | 0 | 56 | 1088 | 509 | 0 | 2780 | 203 | 0 | 444 | 276 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1286 | 809 | 0 | 17446 | 9648 | 344 |

Pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Also requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And for BeautifulSoup: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: sorry, just did :)